# Array iteration in rails controller: it only puts the last value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, controller

I have to iterate on array in my rails controller but it only returns the last value of it:

```
array = ["a", "b", "c"]

 array.each do |arr|
   @arry = arr
 end
```

@arry gives me "c" but I want it to give me a b c

So, when I add a API method in the each iteration, it only gives me a result for the "c" value but I want a result for all of them.

FYI: when I iterate this array in my view, everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.each do |el|
  @arr = el
end
```

Every loop you are saving `el` as `@arr` (overriding previous value)so after full each you have last el. You can do it like this if you want to do something with each element.

```
@arr = array.map { |el| el }
```

or just

```
@arr = array
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` enumerator:

```
@arry = array.map { |arr| arr }
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map